# How to make properties read-only basing on runtime information in EEF wizards

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I'm using EEF to create property editors for an EMF model I'm working on. The model is composed of commands, and each command can be in "EDIT" mode or in "RUNNING" mode. This information is available as derived attribute of each command, and it is controlled by my application logic.

I want to let the user only edit the commands in "EDIT" mode, while I want to make read-only those in "RUNNING" mode... how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution: I need to change the generated code so to check the runtime information and make read-only sensible information.